# I am trying to use dynamic data to change and trigger classnames but it always only result to true despite data containing false. Any solution?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, ternary

I am trying to dynamically change the styles based on ternary classnames.
I am trying to change the background to dark or light based on the input on the workWrapper in here:
[image: I have a Data.js wherein I can just put every data in one file]

[image: Which is connected to this component]

[image: and I am basing it to here]

[image: However, I cannot figure out why the dark classname is not being triggered when I already set the workWrapper value to false/true, it is still light]

The CSS:

```
.normColor{
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.normColor .dark{
  background-color: #232A4E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I already tried messing around with the component, searching for other similar issues to mine and trying to search youtube videos regarding it but I cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to de-structure your props.

try this :-

```
const WorkSection = ({workWrapper}) =>{
    return(<div className={workWrapper?'normColor':'dark'}></div>)
}
```

And you checking `props`, if it is null or not. And it will always give you true, because components always have `props`